# Use dplyr::percent_rank() to compute percentile ranks within group

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data:

```
id    grpvar1    grpvar2    value
1     1          3          7.6
2     1          2          4
...
3     1          5          2
```

For each `id`, I want to compute the `percent_rank()` of its `value` within the group defined by the combination of `grpvar1` and `grpvar2`.

Using `data.table`, I would go (assuming I my data is in a `data.frame` called `dataf`:

```
library(data.table)

# Make dataset into a data.table.
dt <- data.table(dataf)

# Calculate the percentiles.
dt[, percrank := rank(value)/length(value), by = c("grpvar1", "grpvar2")]
```

What is the equivalent in `dplyr`?

Comment: You could try: `dataf %>% group_by(grpvar1, grpvar2) %>% mutate(percrank=rank(value)/length(value))` which gives the output you showed using `data.table`

Comment: There is no a real reason to use `dplyr::percent_rank()` as it is just a simple function that does `(min_rank(x) - 1)/(length(x) - 1)`. It is easier to write `rank(value)/length(value)` than trying to adopt `percent_rank` to your needs

Comment: Akrun, wrap that up in an answer and I'll check it once I confirm it works as intended!

Comment: @Brash Equilibrium Thanks, I posted that as a solution.

Comment: Why is the formula min_rank(x)-1/length(x)-1?  I don't understand the "- 1" part

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
 library(dplyr)
 dataf %>%
 group_by(grpvar1, grpvar2) %>% 
 mutate(percrank=rank(value)/length(value))
```

Comment: This will probably be very slow if done an external dataset in a Postgres database with millions if rows and tens of thousands of groups right?

Comment: @Brash Equilibrium Yes, I would agree.  If the dataset is manageable, `data.table` would be a faster option

Comment: The dataset is not manageable if I bring it all in at once. I'll have to bring in only the stuff I need to do the ranking on, and then take out the garbage after a post ranking aggregation step.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium, not sure what you mean. I can't recall anything you can do with `dplyr` which can't do with `data.table`

Comment: I am talking about dplyr query building capabilities and how it is sometimes faster to do processes in memory than in database, but there is the trade off having to take out the garbage

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium benchmark it - postgres might be able to optimise the query quite a bit, esp. if your indices are set up correctly

Comment: This table has over 28,000,000 records in it and I need them all. It takes an hour just to pull a simple select query on it. My plan is to do that to get the fields I need, then use dplyr or data.table to post-process. In my experience, it's way faster for this dataset. Orders of magnitude faster, really. Like 6 seconds versus...Jesus, I don't even want to think about how long the alternative would take.